# JQuery Plugin: How to expose public method tied to instances

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Having a little difficulty. Trying to expose a public method stop() within a plugin. Multiple plugin instances may be running on a page. I want to be able to do the following:

```
var slider = $('#slider1').myslider();
// later
slider.stop();
```

I have the following:

```
; (function ($) {

    $.fn.myslider = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            interval: 2000
        };
        var o = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var slider = $(this);

            var timer;
            var active;

            var rotateSwitch = function () {
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    active = $('.slider_active', slider).next();
                    if (active.length === 0) {
                        active = $('.slider_paging a:first', slider);
                    }
                    rotate();
                }, o.interval);
            };

            rotateSwitch();
            ...
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

How to a expose a stop() method that I can call for a particular instance?

Comment: what exactly would it do? Call `clearInterval()` on `timer`?

Comment: @lilaG yes, would clear the interval on the timer

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to have your plug-in function accept a command string, e.g.:

```
$(selector).slider("stop");
```

That's what jQuery UI's various plug-ins do, for instance. So you'd modify your function to test for whether it's received an options object (your current code) or a command string, and act accordingly.

In your specific case, you'd have to store the timer value on the elements in question, probably using the `data` function.

Comment: Yep this is prob the best way - if your looking for some code on how to achieve this a pretty good pattern is: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-alert.js : see plugin definition at the bottom